# Associative array in CouchDB keys?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I haven't seen any mention of this around, but is there any way to deal with an associative array key in CouchDB?:

```
map: function(doc) { if (...) { emit({ one: doc.one, two: doc.two, ... }); } }
```

I have a need for some rather dynamic and complex queries, this would help solve that problem (but I'm guessing this completely breaks everything).

Comment: CouchDB view indexes only support arrays when it comes to complex keys. Please describe more of the problem you are trying to solve, I'm willing to bet there is a good solution.

Comment: Data coming in from many vendors, need logic to find existing CouchDB records to attach arbitrary data to. It's a pretty generalized problem— I'll just have to solve it via auto-generated views or move to Mongo, I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All keys are always sorted along one dimension only. Associative array (object) keys are supported by CouchDB. The sort order is well-defined, however it is basically arbitrary and much less intuitive than, for example, arrays, where we all know that the first/leftmost element is most significant.

Additionally, different programming languages, client libraries, and JSON serializers might (and do!) change the order of the keys in the associative array. (Often it does not matter because in **Javascript**, or in most languages really, key order is undefined.)

The [CouchDB collation specification](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation#Collation_Specification) describes the sort order of all valid JSON data, including associative arrays (objects).

*Maybe* you can simulate associative arrays by flattening it into an array and sorting the keys, all o the client side.

```
{"foo":"This value is foo", "A":65, "the":"end"}
```

becomes

```
["A", 65, "foo", "This value is foo", "the", "end"]
```

Comment: I had read the spec to really get your point : you can use a "dict" as a document key, but the order of keys within the dict is significant -- CouchDB will consider 2 dicts to be different if their keys are in a different order ( recursively, i guess for complex objects ).  This does create a problem!  (maybe you could just sort the keys instead of a full "flatten")  Very interesting -- I actually had no idea that you could use a dict at all -- does anyone actually do that, in practice?  Could you solve this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549299/couchdb-and-multiple-keys

Comment: In practice, array keys are much more common. Most applications never use object keys at all.